# GROUP RESULT BY 15 DAYS ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have daily amounts on a table and I need to get the sum of those from a date range. But group it by the first and second half of the month. (every 15 days).

Comment: Is it always a calendar month, or any random period of 30days?  What does your query look like; is the date range hard coded or parameterised?  Show exactly what SQL you have already, some example data and some example results - to demonstrate the exact behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: Every 15 days. Which calendar?

Comment: What about February? Or January, March, May, etc?

Comment: "first and second half of the month" and "every 15 days" are different time periods.  Months may have 28, 29, 30, or 31 days after all.  Do you want rows from midnight on the 1st until 11:59:59 pm on the 15th grouped together and then rows from midnight on the 16th until the end of the month grouped together?

Comment: Might be `group by trunc(datecol, 'mon'), round(datecol, 'mon')`

Comment: @dnoeth - I thought that might be a neat answer. Until I tried it. Turns out `round(date '2020-01-21', 'mon')` gives `date '2020-02-01'`

Comment: @APC Of course, it "rounds" using a simple logic: *1st of month if day <= 15, otherwise 1st of next month*. When you group by both trunc/round you get rows for 1-15 and 16+. Can be simplified to `trunc(trans_date, 'mon') + case when extract(day from trans_date) <= 15 then 0 ELSE 15 END`.

Comment: @dnoeth - oh yeah, I tried it and it works, with one quibble. The Oracle implementation rounds down `date '2019-02-15'`.

Comment: @APC Of course, *1st of month if day <= 15, otherwise 1st of next month*. Ask Oracle, why :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is based on the assumption that first 15 days of a month be treated as 1st half and 16th day till end of month as 2nd half. Also, year is required otherwise multiple years will be grouped together in the output.

```
select to_char(date_col,'YYYY') As Year,
       to_char(date_col,'MON') As Month,
       case when Cast(to_char(date_col,'DD') As integer) <= 15 then '1st_half' else '2nd_half' end As Month_Half,
       SUM(Amount_field)
from my_table
group by 
    to_char(date_col,'YYYY'),
    to_char(date_col,'MON'),
    case when Cast(to_char(date_col,'DD') As integer) <= 15 then '1st_half' else '2nd_half' end;
```

Comment: This is a reasonable stab at a solution, and provides a good basis for the Seeker, once they have figured out the precise business rules (e.g. what to do about February).